# Fire and Forget not getting scheduled

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I am using `Task.Run(() => this.someMethod())` to schedule a back ground job. I am not interested in the operation result and need to move on with flow of application.

But, sometimes my background task is not getting scheduled for a long time.This has started to happen since we moved from .Net 4.7 from 4.5. Even while debugging the break points are either not hit or hit after considerable delay( > 10 minutes).

Has anyone noticed this behavior or know whats causing it?

I am running on i7 core, 16 GB RAM.

Comment: Have you got a lot of other tasks running in the background?

Comment: Here few more inputs:- System is not under any load. This fire and forget operation works sometimes but not all the time as it should. The work in the task is not a long running. It will just connect over the network and send some data , Data is less than 1MB and gets transmitted in few milliseconds. But its important that that time should bot interfere in the main flow.

Answer (score 0):

Having your Task taking 10 minutes to even start sounds fishy. My guess is your system is under heavy load, or you have a lot of tasks running.

I'm going to attack the later (for a specific situation).

[TaskCreationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **LongRunning** Specifies that a task will be a long-running,
>   coarse-grained operation involving fewer, larger components than
>   fine-grained systems. It provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that
>   oversubscription may be warranted. Oversubscription lets you create
>   more threads than the available number of hardware threads. It also
>   provides a hint to the task scheduler that an additional thread might
>   be required for the task so that it does not block the forward
>   progress of other threads or work items on the local thread-pool
>   queue.

```
var task = new Task(() => MyLongRunningMethod(),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
task.Start();
```

This is a quote from [Stephen Toub - MSFT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/stephen%20toub%20-%20msft/) on this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8304b44f-0480-488c-93a4-ec419327183b/when-should-a-taks-be-considered-longrunning?forum=parallelextensions)

> Under the covers, it's going to result in a higher number of threads
>   being used, because its purpose is to allow the ThreadPool to continue
>   to process work items even though one task is running for an extended
>   period of time; if that task were running in a thread from the pool,
>   that thread wouldn't be able to service other tasks.  You'd typically
>   only use LongRunning if you found through performance testing that not
>   using it was causing long delays in the processing of other work.

Its hard to know what is your problem with out looking at all your code, however i posted this as a sugestion.

Comment: No, system is not under any load. I cannot see Task getting scheduled even while debugging and I just trigger one operation. That operation has to invoke fire and forget operation. The code is very simple  public void InAnOperation() {

Do some stuff

Task.Run(() => this.somemethod())

return;
}

public void someMethod() {

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many tasks you start this way, but unless the number is *really* high I would focus the debugging on the method being called, not the caller. A delay of 10 minutes is more likely caused by a deadlock or network issue than the task scheduling.

Some ideas:

1. For a start, I would add something to the beginning and the end of the method being called that lets you know when it starts to execute and when it finishes. Like a Debug.WriteLine() with a timestamp and task ID.
2. Make sure the method being called releases all resources, even if it crashes. Crashing threads/tasks may go unnoticed, because they don't cause the application to crash.
3. Double check that the method being called is thread-safe. You may have been lucky in the past and some new framework optimization is now causing havoc.

Comment: Again, its not many tasks that are running. The issue is Task is not even getting started, I have put a break point to make sure I can catch when it starts, but it never hits it. I am using Fire and Forget at few places but seems a common issue every where. There are no resource issues as well. There are no thread level contentions. I also tried explicit thread like new Thread( () => {}).Start(). Again, no luck. Tried changing the code to a simplest List add method Task.Run( () => List<T>.Add()). Didn't execute :(

Comment: That sounds really strange and according to the Microsoft change logs, there have been no changes to threading or tasks from 4.5 to 4.7. Are you sure the conversion worked fine and didn't break your environment somehow? What happens if you await the task? What status does it have after a few seconds?